OP Stack fraud proofs with malicious sequencer
Finalization in OP stack chains
According to the OP stack documentation on transactions, a transaction is considered finalized when the blob in which the L2 transaction has been made is on Ethereum, and the Ethereum block with the blob is considered final: https://docs.optimism.io/stack/transactions/transaction-finality.
In practice, that means a transaction is considered final after less than 15 minutes.
Assumption
Now consider the following case:

The sequencer is malicious
An attacker sends two transactions spending the same coins twice (say Eve sends 10 ETH to Alice in tx_1 and 10 ETH to Bob in tx_2, but she only has 10 ETH on the L2)
In the normal case, the sequencer should reject either of the two transactions
In our case, the sequencer accepts both transactions and includes them in a blob on Ethereum
Both transactions are considered finalized after 15 minutes

As far as I understand, when the sequencer sends the following proposal claiming both tx_1 and tx_2 to be valid, a challenger should challenge the proposal since double-spends are not allowed. Leaving aside the details of the fraud-proof game (https://docs.optimism.io/stack/fault-proofs/explainer), the state proposal by the malicious sequencer would be disproven.
This would result in:

The malicious sequencer would get slashed for the invalid proposal
The challenger would receive remuneration for correctly proving fraud
The proposed state of the OP stack chain should not include tx_1 or tx_2

There's now a mismatch between "finalized" as per the blobs on Ethereum and state proposals.
Questions
Since finality does not depend on the finality of the proposals but on the finalized Ethereum blobs, what should the actual state of the L2 be? If transactions are finalized when they are in an Ethereum-confirmed blob, then there's a conflict between the fraud-proven state (includes only tx_1 or tx_2) and the Ethereum blob (includes both tx_1 and tx_2).
In practice, I see a few issues:

If tx_1 and tx_2 were used with a third-party bridge to send the ETH to other chains, the third-party bridges should not use the "finalized" state of the blobs, but they should use the 7 days of fraud-proof time to consider a transaction as finalized, or they should be running a full node of the OP stack chain to validate its correctness with their own added check if a transaction is finalized but incorrect.
If tx_1 and tx_2 were used in DEX swaps, then the DEX balances would be incorrect. How would this be resolved? Would the state of the DEX need to be updated/corrected?


After some more digging in the Optimism specs (https://specs.optimism.io/protocol/derivation.html#sequencing--batch-submission-overview), I finally found a solution to this.
The issue is that "finalization" as per OP stack is different to "finality" typically used in consensus protocols. "Finalization" in OP stack terms means that a valid or invalid transaction is stored in the DA layer (Ethereum blobs or others). The important bit is that "finalized" transactions can be invalid.
Verifiers running a full node of the L2 would detect that a transaction is invalid and consider the L2 state incorrect if the sequencer were to propose a block that includes an invalid transaction.
In practice, third-party bridge operators, DEX, or other protocols would run their full nodes to verify that the blocks produced by the sequencer are correct by deriving the L2 state from the DA data. If the sequencer proposes an incorrect state to Ethereum, these full nodes could start the fraud-proof procedure.

Interesting insight. So, ideally, all third-party bridges, DEXs, etc., running on any chain (utilizing the OP Stack) should run their own set of challenger nodes separately, instead of relying on the actions of other challengers?

Yes, I think for all optimistic rollups (including Arbitrum) large apps should run full nodes. I think this would also be necessary for zk rollups like Starknet since typically they also consider transaction finalized before the zk proof is verified on Ethereum (at which point an invalid proof would be rejected).
